# Tell dlopen in which library to search for symbols first

Tags: c++, c, shared-libraries, dlopen

I have a shared library `libmylib.so` which uses `libstdc++.so`
There is another shared library that contains symbols with the same names of the symbols of `libstdc++.so`. The library name is `libmystd.so`

`libmystd.so` is loaded first, and then I use `dlopen` in order to open `libmylib.so`
The problem is that the symbols are loaded from `libmystd.so` instead of `libstdc++.so`. How can I tell `dlopen` to search for the symbols in `libstdc++.so` first instead of `libmystd.so`

This is how I open `libmylib.so` using `dlopen`

```
myHandle = dlopen("libmylib.so", RTLD_GLOBAL | RTLD_NOW)
```

Then I call a function from this shared library, but it crashes because the `std::vercotr` destructor is called from `libmystd.so` instead of `libstdc++.so`

```
0xedb4e936 _ZNSt6vectorISsSaISsEED2Ev + 76     libmystd.so
 0xeb9494ff _ZN10MySymbolESs + 1db      libmylib.so
```

Comment: Are you *really* trying to run a process with two different versions of C++ run-time libraries at the same time?

Comment: @AndrewHenle can this be achieved?

Comment: If you would show the code using `dlopen(filename, mode)` and its likely subsequent `dlsym(handle, name)` the issue would be clearer.

Comment: @Ripi2 I added the dlopen code

Comment: @Tyker *but with `dlopen` and `dlsym` you should be fine*  Not really.  Even if you somehow can control direct calls by using `dlsym` (how are you going to determine the mangled name used by the linker?), you can't control what the code in those calls does. In this case, if you make a call into `libstdc++.so` using `dlsym()`, the code you call may very well wind up using symbols from `libmystd.so`. And good luck if you're using templates...

Comment: Are you maybe looking for `LD_PRELOAD`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I tell dlopen to search for the symbols in libstdc++.so first instead of libmystd.so

You can load `libstdc++.so` first, and then its symbols will "win".

Presumably this is a problem for you because you want some other code to use `libmystd.so` *instead* of `libstdc++.so`.

There is really *no way* to mix two separate instances of C++ runtime in a single process safely. Any approach that will appear to work will have hidden gotcha's and will *not really* work (and debugging this will be painful).

The only sane approach is to either build code for exactly one of the implementations (and use *that* implementation), or to have two separate processes (each using the implementation it was compiled for) and use some form of inter-process communication between them.

Comment: In the end I used 2 separate processes